# Есть цикл в RetailCRM выдающий отображение для свойств товара — нужно чтобы выводило только если значение равно определенному, а не все

Tags: php

Настраиваю триггер в RetailCRM, там есть цикл

```
{% for of,od in product.properties %}

    {% for key, val in od %}
        {% if key == 'name' %}{{val}}: 
        {% endif %}
        {% if key == 'value' %}{{val}}
        {% endif %}{% endfor %}<br>
    {% endfor %}</td>
```

этот цикл выводит все свойства `name` и `value`, которые есть, а мне нужно чтобы выводил только если **`name = "color"`**. 
Тогда выводит, если другим значениям, то не выводит.

Как правильно внести исправления?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте данный вариант:

```
{% for of,od in product.properties %}
    {% for key, val in od %}
        {% if val == 'color' %}
            if {% key == 'name' %} 
                {{val}}: 
            {% endif %}

            if {% key == 'value' %} 
                {{val}}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Было бы неплохо, если более детальнее описали задачу)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло! Правда есть нюанс, получается мне нужно выводить VALUE только для name = 'color', как это правильно отразить?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1qqvseg7w46f80b/Screenshot%202021-06-27%20at%2011.48.42%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: Попробуйте новый вариант @sasha-scream

Comment: Что-то сломалось, почему-то ругается на строку где if вне {% %} конструкции

Comment: Хмм, возможно шаблонизатор не понял условие в одну строку, обновил код, если снова будет ругаться, скриншот ошибки скиньте

Comment: Сообразил — if загнать под скобки конструкции, только кажется логическая ошибка → `val` → теперь отображатся только когда равен "color".

Comment: `val` отображается только если значение равно "color". Но получается нужно так: отображать для значение `key "name" = "color"` тогда отображать для него `key "value"' → а то сейчас отображается хоть `key name`, хоть `key value` только если значение "color".

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ez7tyk8vdrzim8l/Screenshot%202021-06-27%20at%205.51.01%20PM.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы вывести свойства товаров, добавленные в заказе, используйте код

```
{% for prod in order.availableOrderProducts %}
    {% for item in prod.properties %}
        {{ item.code }} {{ item.name }} {{ item.value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Чтобы вывести свойства товаров, добавленные в каталоге —

```
{% for prod in order.availableOrderProducts %}
    {% for item in prod.offer|offer_properties %}
        {{ item.code }} {{ item.name }} {{ item.value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Как можете видеть, одни свойства выводятся через массив объекта внутри заказа, а другие через фильтр массива внутри каталога.

`item` — можете заменить на то, что вам нравится, по сути это именование переменной при обработке массива.

`item.code` — код формируется автоматически путем транслитерации

`item.name` — название свойства

`item.value` — значение свойства

Далее перебирайте нужные вам названия по фильтру if. Например такой пример выведет название и значение свойства товара указанные в каталоге (не в заказе), только если название свойства будет color, а имя свойства будет равно blue или red.

```
{% for prod in order.availableOrderProducts %}
    {% for item in prod.offer|offer_properties %}
        {% if item.name == 'color' and item.value in ['blue', 'red'] %}
            {{ item.name }} {{ item.value }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Но в триггерах не работает Twig, этот код будет работать только в шаблонах (печатный формы, письма, смс). В триггерах используется Pipeline который работает иначе. Поэтому для более точного ответа стоит детальнее понять, вы пишете триггер или всё же шаблон?